# How do I re add a control that lost it's parent groupbox?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2013

**Problem** I recently had a form with buttons, radiobuttons, etc within a group box. I deleted the groupbox, but kept it's contents. Unfortunately, now whenever I'm in the designer editing, and I move one of those controls, I get this error:

[image]

"Value cannot be null. Parameter Name: child."

So, From what I could tell from some searching is that one of the parameters is set to NULL. In this case it is the child/parent parameter of the control.

**Question** How do I reset this parameter? I didn't see it shown in the properties nor the designer.cs.

**What I've tried**

I tried one of the radio button sets by deleting and creating new ones in the form. This caused the two radio buttons go into stack overflow, for when I click one it tries to NOT the value of the other, and the other does the same. This creates a sort of infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried searching the designer for the name of the control you removed?

Comment: Yep. It's not in there. I checked the document outline too. This doesn't happen in run time, only while editing. But because of it, my radio buttons don't work.

Comment: How exactly did you perform the step: `I deleted the groupbox, but kept it's contents.`?

Comment: Using the document outline window, I moved the items outside of the groupbox's drop down to the same level as the other items on the form (but not in any group), then deleted the groupbox. Usually I would select and drag them out, then select the box and delete. But some items were hidden and hard to see.